# Can one force String.valueOf() to return unsigned value in Java?

Tags: java, formatting

I have a byte array:

```
byte[] a = new byte[3];
```

which I have added some bytes.  For this example, let's say 3, 4, and 210.

I would like to print this string of bytes to look like `3 4 210`, but instead I get `3 4 -46`

I am using `String.valueOf(a[i])` to do my conversion.  Is there any way to force this conversion to give unsigned values?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT:**  Thanks to the various feedback on this question.  I had not realized Java Bytes were signed values by default, and so was suspecting the String.valueOf() method as being the issue.  It turns out just simply using

```
String.valueOf(a[i]&0xFF)
```

takes care of the signed formatting issue.

Again, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: There is no unsigned type in Java. If you want that to print `210`, then why not just take an `int[]`?

Comment: Thank you for your time and feedback.  I'm learning this Java one day at a time. I did not realize that Java bytes were signed.  Let me go through the responses and process them...

Answer (score 3):

Guava provides a [`UnsignedBytes`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html) class that can make that conversion. The `static` `toString(byte)` method

> Returns a string representation of x, where x is treated as unsigned.

For example

```
System.out.println(UnsignedBytes.toString(a[i]));
```

where `a[i] = -46` would print

```
210
```

Internally, all this does is call

```
public static int toInt(byte value) {
    return value & UNSIGNED_MASK; // UNSIGNED_MASK = 0xFF
}
```

and convert the `int` to a `String` which it returns.

---

For an explanation

With

```
someByte & 0xFF
```

since OxFF is an integer literal, the `someByte` value is widened to an `int`. Let's take for example the value `-46`. Its binary representation is

```
11111111111111111111111111010010
```

The binary representation of `0xFF` is

```
11111111 // ie 255
```

if you *and* `&` the two

```
11111111111111111111111111010010
00000000000000000000000011111111 
--------------------------------
00000000000000000000000011010010
```

which is equal to

```
210
```

Basically you only keep the lower 8 bits of the `int`.

Comment: A dependency for something this simple?

Comment: @seand That's why I also provided the source if they want to copy it. (But Guava is that kind of library that most projects should have anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Java byte data type range is minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). `String.valueOf(a[i])` doesn't do this conversion. Use `int` type instead.

Answer (score 1):

[byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) 
byte range limit is within -128 to 127,
so for 210 it gives -46. so convert it using int type

Comment: You've described the problem, but it looks like the OP already knew this. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You've run into Java's famous problem of bytes treated as signed even though most of the real world prefers these unsigned.  Try this:

```
int[] signedArr = new int[a.length];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
  signedArr[i] = a[i] & 0xff;
}
```

Then you can work with signedArr.

Comment: Wouldn't this just let b through?

Comment: Your answer was better before you edited it.  There's no need for a whole array, when all the OP wants to do is print the values.  Just do the `a[i] & 0xff` part and print what comes out.

Comment: @mharris7190 No, because the `&` does an implicit cast of both sides to `int`.